# Oracle trigger to update a column value in the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am in the need of a trigger which will fire on any insert or updates on the specific table and while inserting or updating will substitute a credit card number column of the new row to something bogus such as "1111 1111 1111 1111"

Here is what I cooked up but it doesn't  seem to work.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name  AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
update table1 set cc_number_field = '11';
END;
```

I am on Oracle 10 if that matters.

Answer (score 10):

It's much easier to manipulate the incoming `:NEW` line with a "before" trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_cc_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.cc_number_field := '1111 1111 1111 1111';
END;
/
```

Comment: Mureinik - you beat me to it - posted while I was assembling my answer!  :-)

Comment: Worked like Magic!!! I tried same approach (using NEW) and it bombed out. I guess I had my syntax wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
  BEFORE
    INSERT on  ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
begin
:new.cc_number_field = '11'; 
END;

[PL/SQL Reference - Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020)